# PHP search function - erroneous results

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple search function in php, the user inserts his search query in a textbox:

```
<form action="inc/search.inc.php" method="post">
            <input id="searchbox" name="search" class="search" type="text"></input>
            </form>
```

My search.inc.page redirects the user to an URL with the query:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"
        && !empty($_POST["search"]))
{
        $searchquery=$_POST["search"];
        header("Location: ../search.php?qr=".$searchquery);
}
?>
```

My search.php calls the function retrieveSearch:

```
<?php 
include_once 'inc/functions.inc.php';
include_once 'inc/db.inc.php';

$db2 = new PDO(DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$qr = (isset($_GET["qr"])) ? (string) $_GET["qr"] : NULL;

$e2 = retrieveSearch($db2, $qr);

$qresult = array_pop($e2);

echo $qresult;
 foreach ($e2 as $row)
 {
     echo $row["title"]."<br/>  ";
 }
?>
```

retrieveSearch function:

```
function retrieveSearch($db2, $qr=NULL)
{
    $sql2 = "SELECT id, title, resume, search
            FROM blog
            WHERE search LIKE ?";
    $stmt2 = $db2->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->execute(array($_GET["qr"]));
    $e2 = $stmt2->fetch();

    array_push($e2, $qr);
    return $e2;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is returning me some weird results, if for example I search for "fff" (one of my 'search' entries), I get the following:

```
fff3
3
f
f
<
<
f
f
```

The 3 infront of 'fff' is the id - which I have no clue where it came from, the other characters seem to be the first letter/symbol of every column... even though I specifically said I only wanted the "title" column displayed.

Comment: What do you get when you try a `var_dump($e2)`?

Comment: array(8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" [0]=> string(1) "3" ["title"]=> string(3) "fff" [1]=> string(3) "fff" ["resume"]=> string(10) "

Comment: function retrieveSearch($db2, $qr=NULL)  -> do you need $qr=NULL ?

Comment: I think your `array_pop` might be causing the issue - it's stripping off the first entry of the results. Maybe try commenting it out and seeing what happens?

Comment: $stmt2->execute(array($_GET["qr"])); i think, should be $qr

Comment: PDO experts, Please clarify, why $stmt2->execute(array($_GET["qr"])); when the function is having $qr function retrieveSearch($db2, $qr=NULL) ?

Comment: Also be aware the you're not URL-encoding the values when you do a redirect so searching for something eg with a `&` or `?` would cause problems and might even break your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at documentation of [PDOStatement::fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

What happens: You fetch only the first row of results and then iterating over its columns. 'title' string is then converted to int (evaluated as zero) and result is the first character of each column.

Comment: Ok, I will try to connect without using PDO.

Comment: You can just use another method: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: fetchAll fixed this! Cheers pal.

Comment: @Josef, Can you please clarify, why $stmt2->execute(array($_GET["qr"])); when the function is having $qr function retrieveSearch($db2, $qr=NULL) ?

Comment: @FirmView There's no reason for that. As well as for other things in the code (like pushing argument to result array). (But maybe you meant to ask author of the code? .])

Comment: yeah!, its for all PDO experts, like to know

Comment: Ok, the NULL part is just to make an else, in case the user tries to access the search page via URL (without any query), it's probably not the best way to do this, but yeah...

Comment: @JoaoFerreira Thanks for responding, but you already checking, $qr = (isset($_GET["qr"])) ? (string) $_GET["qr"] : NULL;

Comment: That is checking the URL, if it finds "qr" it saves the value in a string, if not.. it sends a NULL. So now I can use if (isset($qr)) on the beginning of my retrieveSearch function, and make an else case if a NULL was sent in.